# How to replace system information in grub

Tags: centos, grub

I cloned my disk with zabbix server running on centos 8 and program used for cloning broke grub.
Both disks cannot start, now on cloned disk I installed fresh system without removing old data ( I had a lot of unallocated space).
Question is: how I can switch records in grub(or anywhere I need) to start old Centos ?

Answer (score 0):

You should start CentOS with emergency/recovery mode and from there, check what was used to boot and edit the grub.conf file using it as example.

https://computingforgeeks.com/booting-centos-rhel-into-emergency-mode-recovery-mode/

You will need the CentOS 8 ISO to boot and then remount the drives:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
```